# how to install pecl memcached?

Tags: ubuntu, php, memcached, pecl

i need to install memcahced (not memcache) on my computer (ubuntu 10.10 and php 5.3.3), i did the follwoing:
$ apt-get install php5-memcached libmemcached-tools libmemcached5
**=>DONE SUCESSFULLY**
$ pecl install memcached
*it ends with the following error*

```
checking for libmemcached location... configure: error: memcached support 
requires libmemcached. Use --with-libmemcached-dir= to specify the prefix 
where  libmemcached headers and library are located
```

any idea is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use pecl. Install memcached extension module for PHP5:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install php5-memcached
```

test.php:

```
<?php
        $m = new Memcached();
        $m->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
        var_dump($m->getStats());
?>

$ php test.php 
array(1) {
  ["127.0.0.1:11211"]=>
  array(24) {
    ["pid"]=>
    int(2462)
    ["uptime"]=>
    int(129)
```

To test memcached use telnet:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
STAT pid 2462
STAT uptime 1039
STAT time 1298284545
STAT version 1.4.5
STAT pointer_size 32
STAT rusage_user 0.092005
STAT rusage_system 0.000000
```

Comment: i did already... it keeps giving me RES_WRITE_FAILURE response code on set or add
and gives "SOME ERRORS WERE REPORTED" on getstats

Comment: @Alaa test connection to memcached

Comment: using telnet:

stats
STAT pid 9012
STAT uptime 14
STAT time 1298285340
STAT version 1.2.6
STAT pointer_size 32
STAT rusage_user 0.000000
STAT rusage_system 0.000000
STAT curr_items 0
STAT total_items 0
STAT bytes 0
STAT curr_connections 2
STAT total_connections 3
STAT connection_structures 3
STAT cmd_get 0
STAT cmd_set 0
STAT get_hits 0
STAT get_misses 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT bytes_read 7
STAT bytes_written 0
STAT limit_maxbytes 1073741824
STAT threads 1
but why do i get errors when use PHP!! :((

Comment: Add output `php -i` memcached section

Comment: Version 1.0.2, 
libmemcached version 0.40,
Session support yes,
igbinary support no

Comment: add output: php -r '$m = new Memcached(); $m->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211); var_dump($m->getStats());'

Comment: PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
array(1) {
  ["127.0.0.1:11211"]=>
  array(24) {
    ["pid"]=>
    int(9012)
    ["uptime"]=>
    int(8118)
    ["threads"]=>
    int(1)
    ["time"]=>
    int(1298293444)
    ["pointer_size"]=>
    int(32)
    ["rusage_user_seconds"]=>
    int(0)
    ["rusage_user_microseconds"]=>
    int(172010)
**To be Continued in the next comment**

Comment: ["rusage_system_seconds"]=>int(0)
["rusage_system_microseconds"]=>
int(244015)
["curr_items"]=>
int(0)
["total_items"]=>
int(0)
["limit_maxbytes"]=>
int(1073741824)
["curr_connections"]=>
int(2)
["total_connections"]=>
int(4)
["connection_structures"]=>
int(3)
["bytes"]=>
int(0)
["cmd_get"]=>
int(0)
    ["cmd_set"]=>
    int(0)
    ["get_hits"]=>
    int(0)
    ["get_misses"]=>
    int(0)
    ["evictions"]=>
    int(0)
    ["bytes_read"]=>
    int(37)
    ["bytes_written"]=>
    int(472)
    ["version"]=>
    string(5) "1.2.6"
  }
}

Comment: it seems the problem was with my apache!! even i restarted it before..
but now,, i restarted it, and it works fine... Thanks alot ooshro. i really appreciate your time and help

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by installing libmemcached-devel (I'm on Centos 5.5)